# Not able to run Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have windows 8 pre-installed in my machine. WP8 emulator requires HYPER-V to be enabled in OS but current version of my OS doesn't support HYPER-V feature , but my hardware supports virtualization (I run VMWare on this machine). So my questions are -

1. Is there any way/hack to run emulator on win8 OS?
2. How do I upgrade from current OS to windows 8 Pro(I don't have
   product key as OS was preinstalled in machine)

*WP8 - Windows Phone 8

Answer (score 1):

If you want Hyper-V, you'll need to upgrade to Windows 8(.1) Pro. There's a built-in feature to do that. In Windows 8.1 just search for `more features` in Windows settings (Win+W) and click on the only hit. [Here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6673-add-features-windows-8-a.html) is a more detailed guide for Windows 8.

Comment: For adding new feature I need to have Key which I dont have becuase WIN8 was preinstalled in my machine

Comment: @DeependraMehrotra Yes, you need to buy that key to enable additional features.